# Implicit Differentiation to find equation if the tangent line to a curve

Tags: derivatives

Use implicit differentiation to find an equation of the tangent line to the curve:
$x^2+y^2=(2x^2+2y^2-x)^2$

At the point:
$(0, \frac{1}{2})$

Hi I'm really lost with this question, can somebody please work through it for me so I have a example for my other questions. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating both sides, we get:

$2x+2yy'=2(2x^2+2y^2-x)*(4x+4yy'-1)$.

Plugging in $x=0, y=\frac 12$, we get:

$y'=2y'-1$,

or $y'=1$.

Therefore, $y-\frac 12=y'(0)(x-0)=x$.
This will be transformed into:

$y=x+\frac 12$, which is the equation for tangent line at $x=0$.